# how to get all html elements inside parent element using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get all descendent HTML elements within parent element and then place each of them in separate variables. E.g. for below HTML

```
<div id="Todo">
    <p class="items">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <span class="task">Task</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

I already have `#Todo` in a variable called `$el = $('#Todo')`. I need a generic solution. I mean the code should only work for above piece of HTML but also it should work on any type of HTML code which could have several descendent elements. **How can I achieve this?**

**UPDATE**

Out put will be to place all these elements to its own variables for easy access so whenever I need to access any element inside `#Todo` then I should not use something like `$('#Todo').children('.items')` or not use `.find()` etc.

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: Expected output? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I had guessed so. Don't do it, that's a terrible idea.

Comment: You can do `var elementsinsideparent = $el.children();` and then you have all children of #Todo as a list. If that's what you are asking for.

Comment: How do you name the identifiers? "p", "ps", "p.items", "h1"?  What about the structure(_nested elements_), dynamically appended elements?

Comment: @undefined elements could be any html element and it could have any id or class. These elements could be both already added DOM elements and dynamically appended.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using all selector `*`:

```
$('#Todo *');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KjE3g/1/)**

to get them in array use `.get()`:

```
var childelements = $('#Todo *').get();
```

Comment: Any other way to do it?

Comment: @2619: why? What exactly do you need and what does this approach not do that you need?

Comment: Nit: Technically the elements you select are descendants, not only children.

Comment: @2619: do you want immediate childrens only??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I need all children.

Comment: @2619: this should be the feasible solution for you then

Comment: Is there are way to get those children too which are added later to DOM using jquery? This will do for only those which are already in the DOM.

Comment: You need to determine a way to distinguish between the existing DOM and appended DOM. You could do that by adding some class to child elements in either one case. say you add class `ext` existing DOM children. You can get the length of only appended element after appending using` $('#Todo *').length-$('#Todo .ext').length`

Comment: @2619: I think you are using the wrong terminology. It seems you want to get all *descendants* of the `#Todo` node, not only its children. The phrase "all children" doesn't make a lot of sense in this context. Consider this real world analogy: The child of my own child is not my child. It's my grand-child, or *descendant*. Similarly, I'm not my grand-children's parent, I'm their grandparent, or *ancestor*. So, the `h1` element is a *descendant* of `#Todo`, not a child. Without using the right terminology, you won't be able to effectively communicate your problem.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you. you got what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This is in `jquery`. Variable `'x'` will contain all the children of parent-

```
   var x = $('#Todo').parent().children();
```

Comment: This is will give p tag and then to find more the you will need to use children() on p too. which I do not want.